# Laravel - No funciona el hash del password en el signin y login

Tags: laravel

estoy haciendo el registro y login con laravel, y parece que hay un problema con la encriptacion en la password:

```
public function register(Request $request){

    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(),User::$rules);

    if($validation->fails()){
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Datos no validos.','errors'=>$validation->errors()],400);
    }

    $name = $request->get('name');
    $password = $request->get('password','test');
    $email = $request->get('email');
    $status = Status::whereName('PENDIENTE')->first();

    $user = User::create([
        'name'=>$name,
        'email'=>$email,
        'password'=>Hash::make($password),
        'status_id'=>$status->id
    ]);

    if($user){
        return response()->json(['message'=>'El usuario se ha creado correctamente..!!']);
    } else{
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Ha ocurrido un error al crear el usuario'],400);
    }

}


public function login(Request $request){

    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(),['name'=>'required','password'=>'required']);
    $name = $request->get('name');
    $password = $request->get('password');

    if ($validation->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['message'=>$validation->errors()], 400);
    }

    $user = User::where('name',$name)
    ->where('password',Hash::make($password))
    ->first();

    if ($user) {
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Ha iniciado sesión correctamente.']);
    }
    else{
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Error al iniciar sesión.'],400);
    }
}
```

El tema es que al guardar yo lo estaba haciendo por `bcrypt()` pero he buscado otra alternativa a ver si era por algun problema con esa funcion, asi que lo he cambiado por `Hash::make()` . Y sigue sin funcionar, deberia de tirar sin problemas. La password viene en texto plano desde el front y se **hashea** en el back. Pero a la hora de **guardar** o **comprobar el usuario** hay algo que falla que no consigo ver. Es realmente extraño pues tiene la logica base para que funcione.

---

El error veo que esta a la hora de comprobar el usuario, hago un query para ver un usuario con dicho nombre y password  y siempre retorna null, y la password obviamente la se porque estoy testeando.

Comment: Hola, has probado con el metodo de autenticación que laravel trae por defecto? if (Auth::attempt(['name'=>$request->get('name'),'password'=>$request->get('password')])) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return redirect()->intended('principal'); //aqui va el nombre de tu ruta
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error parte de que haces `hash` de la contraseña que llega del front cada que el user intenta `log in`.

Por lo tanto esta condición no se va a cumplir:

```
->where('password',Hash::make($password))
```

Pues el valor que `make()` retorne será distinto cada vez que lo invoques (*en este caso cada que el user intenta ingresar con sus credenciales*)

Ahora del mismo facade `Hash` que ya estás empleando, el método que deberías emplear es [`Hash::check`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/hashing#verifying-that-a-password-matches-a-hash) en el cual:

- El primer argumento es el string del password en texto plano que envía el user
- El segundo argumento es el hash del password que el user guardó cuando se registró

Siendo `true` o  `false` el posible valor de retorno.

Finalmente el usar [`bcrypt`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-bcrypt) no debería ser problema, pues dicho *helper* es solo una alternativa al *facade* que ya estás empleando.